# Allowing multiple services in docker-compose to share a merged volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Given a `docker-compose.yml` file like below, I'm looking for a way that both service `a` and `b` can have access to a shared volume which consists of the *merged* contents of both containers.

```
version: '3'
volumes:
   shared-merged-volume:
services:
   a:
     volumes:
       - shared-merged-volume:/shared
   b:
     volumes:
       - shared-merged-volume:/shared
```

Let's say service `a` has a directory at `/shared/dir-from-a` and service `b` has a similar `/shared-dir-from-b` directory.  The desired result is to end up with:

```
$ ls /shared # from either container
dir-from-a
dir-from-b
```

What I find is that one of the containers "wins" and only one of those two directories is ever present.  I can work around the issue like this but is more verbose and requires modification if directory contents ever changes:

```
version: '3'
volumes:
   service-a-shared-volume:
   service-b-shared-volume:
services:
   a:
     volumes:
       - service-a-shared-volume:/shared/dir-from-a
       - service-b-shared-volume:/shared/dir-from-b
   b:
     volumes:
       - service-a-shared-volume:/shared/dir-from-a
       - service-b-shared-volume:/shared/dir-from-b
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Have you found a working solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Is using a named volume a requirement?

If not, then to accomplish such merging I usually just map directories to one location on the host drive, instead of using volumes, and it merges with no problems. Tested on big loads and multiple containers writing simultaneously.

proposed compose file:

```
version: '3'
volumes:
   shared-merged-volume:
services:
   a:
     volumes:
       - /location/on/host/system:/shared
   b:
     volumes:
       - /location/on/host/system:/shared
```

**Edit from comments**

This method mounts everything that's in the local host directory to the `/shared`, meaning if it's empty - it'll mount the empty dir, and whatever was there - will be overwritten by the empty dir. Everything that will be written inside that mount after your service starts, will be persisted and merged across services as expected.

Comment: Thanks!  That seems to wipe out any existing contents of `/shared` on each service, which is not what I quite want.  I want the merged contents of each `/shared` from every container

Comment: That's strange. It never erased anything from the location if I didn't do so myself. We should investigate deeper then. What is your docker and docker-compose version?

Comment: Docker version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40
docker-compose version 1.21.1, build 5a3f1a3

Comment: Ok, apparently I have the same versions. But I think I misunderstood you, this method mounts everything that's in the local host directory to the `/shared`, meaning if it's empty - it'll mount the empty dir, and whatever will be written inside that mount after service starts, will be persisted and merged across services.

Comment: Yup, that's not quite what I want!  Each container has it's own set of files in `/shared` and I want them to be shared between all containers.  Thanks anyway for pitching in :)

Comment: Well, this case is interesting. Are those files created only once while building and not after the service starts?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171358/discussion-between-jayp-and-trust512).

Answer (score 0):

If both containers are creating *different* folders, I don't see how they can be contending to create their own respective folders, unless they both delete the contents of `/shared` first, then they create the folders? But that would mean that the use of volumes in this case is null because the contents will be deleted every time the container starts?

In any case, I find that it is often useful to persuade the containers to share the same folder by use of path redirection. I will share two ways of accomplishing this:

1. If you have access to the code that creates the folders in `/shared`, then you can use environment variables to change the expected location of `/shared` for each service

   ```yaml
   version: '3'
   volumes:
     shared-merged-volume:
   services:
     a:
       environment:
         SHARED_VOLUME_PATH: /shared/a/
       volumes:
         - shared-merged-volume:/shared
     b:
       environment:
         SHARED_VOLUME_PATH: /shared/b/
       volumes:
         - shared-merged-volume:/shared
   ```

   You may need to have the services create `SHARED_VOLUME_PATH`, but now they can both live peaceably with each other.
2. If you are unable to change the location of `/shared`, which means each service will always want to use that path, another way to create path redirection is to use symbolic links. *For this to work, you will have to override the entrypoint of your services **or** do this step during the build process of the  image*.

   ```yaml
   version: '3'
   volumes:
     shared-merged-volume:
   services:
     a:
       entrypoint: [ "ln", "-sf", "/symshared/a/", "/shared/" ]
       volumes:
         - shared-merged-volume:/symshared
     b:
       entrypoint: [ "ln", "-sf", "/symshared/b/", "/shared/" ]
       volumes:
         - shared-merged-volume:/symshared
   ```

   Alternatively, build the images ahead of time, and add a simple `RUN` command in the `Dockerfile` which creates this symbolic link:

   ```
   ...
   ARG SHARED_VOLUME_PATH
   RUN ln -sf ${SHARED_VOLUME_PATH} /shared/
   ```

   What this allows you to do is that each container will keep using `/shared` as they used to, but you will still be able to store it's content in the volume, without interfering with what other containers want to do with their own version of `/shared`.

   Needless to say, the `ln` command only works on linux and other unixes, and in some cases, you may need to install it prior. If your container image is based on something else like windows for example, then find something else that can be used to create symlinks.